# replacement in Python 3.6 for u = urllib.urlopen('http://ctabustracker.com/bustime/map/getBusesForRoute.jsp?route=22')

Tags: python-3.6

```
import urllib

u = urllib.urlopen('http://ctabustracker.com/bustime map/getBusesForRoute.jsp?route=22')
data = u.read()
f = open('rt22.xml', 'wb')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

## In python 3.6, what function replaces urllib.urlopen?

## from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=RrPZza_vZ3w

## at 17.41

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib

u = urllib.request.urlopen('http://ctabustracker.com/bustime map/getBusesForRoute.jsp?route=22')
data = u.read()
f = open('rt22.xml', 'wb')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

you can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)